# How to run react project on http and access through other devices?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When I run the project locally with the `yarn dev`, I can see that

**

> project is running at http://192.XX.XX

**

But when I click there, the webpage is unable to connect.

Is it possible to access it? I need it for connecting it through my phone to test the webpage layout.